# Line number constant in Actionscript 3.0?

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging, constants

Is there a line number constant or way to dynamically trace the line number in actionscript?

Does actionscript have the equivalent of

```
__LINE__
```

in PHP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a CONSTANT but this line of code will give you the line number:

```
trace(">",new Error().getStackTrace().match(/(?<=:)[0-9]*(?=])/g)[0]);
```

PS: this will only work if the swf is compiled in debug mode

Comment: Interesting approach. This has got me thinking about the problem in a new way. Thanks. What other useful information do you often pull out of the stack trace? Do you ever use this technique to create conditional breakpoints in the code? For example adding a break point when a very specific parameter has been passed to a function? I suppose in that case one could just put in conditional test for the parameter and wrap a break point inside it.

Comment: hi !
i never use this trick... and i am not sure we can add dynamicly breakpoints in as3... but in order to debug your application, you can still throw an exception...
hope that will help you... sorry i am french, my english is very poor... : (

Answer (score 3):

To use OXMO456's trick as a function, just use index 1 of the `match` result (rather than index 0).  The code below does this and checks for debug capability:

```
import flash.system.Capabilities;

/**
 * Returns the positive line number from which the function is called, if
 * available, otherwise returns a negative number.
 */
function lineNumber():int {
  var ret:int = -1;
  if (Capabilities.isDebugger) {
    ret = new Error().getStackTrace().match(/(?<=:)[0-9]*(?=])/g)[1];
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Example:

```
trace('line ' + lineNumber() + ' reached!');
```